# How to check node value in the XML string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to catch the exception which is returing XML as string.

```
private static string SerializeException(Exception ex)
{
    return SerializableException.ExceptionSerializer.GetSerializedData(ex);
}
```

and from that

```
public static bool HandleError( string message, Exception exception))   
{
     string exceptionString = SerializeException(exception);
     //Which is giving me the complete xml string.
     //But here I have to check only one node from the exceptionString.
     // Below condtion is giving wrong results ,because it contains the Empty xml. 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(exceptionString))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Once exception is there in the above method I have to send to Windows service bus, but before sending that I have to check is exception is serialzed properly or not.

Can anybody suggest how to check a node value from the string?

Comment: What do you mean by "because it contains the empty XML"? You've given us all the context *around* the problem, but you haven't described the actual problem itself - what does the XML look like, and what are you trying to get out of it? It sounds like you should be able to just parse the XML (e.g. with LINQ to XML) and fetch the appropriate node - at which point the problem has pretty much nothing to do with serializing exceptions.

Comment: The root cause is XML is not properly serialized in SerializeException method, so better look for xml and the SerializeException  method, why its returning empty string..